# How can I hide "fast-forward" commits in gitk?

Tags: git, gitk

I have this kind of tree :

```
J
|\
| I
| H
| G
| |\
| | F
| | E
| | D
| |/
| C
| B
|/
A
```

How can I make it look like this (or similar) in gitk ?

```
J
|\
| G,H,I
| |\
| | D,E,F
| |/
| B,C
|/
A
```

My history tree become hard to read when a merged functionality has many commits.

---

**Edit :** I tried `gitk --merges` but it gives me something like that :

```
J
|\
| I
A

G
|\
| F
C
```

---

**Edit :** The example tree can be found in this repo : https://github.com/moobee/gitk-hide-ff-commit

Comment: `gitk --merges` seems weird.
It gives me something like my edit in the question.

Comment: Yeah I know, its not the same as what you want. But maybe close to what you want. You can look into [git-log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for other options..

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as a "fast forward commit".  There are fast forward merges, but you don't have any of that here.

Comment: The commits that I want to hide are not the `merge commits`.
How are called the following commits : I, H, F, E and C ?

Comment: You want to visually squash any commit with exactly one parent into its parent, *and combine their log messages* -- I don't think gitk has a way of doing that.  You might be able to do it with some postprocessing of one of the git -> dot plotting schemes though.

Comment: A very similar tool called `gitg` has an option called "Collapse inactive lanes" which I thought sounded like a good description of what you (and I) want.  Unfortunately, the option seems to have no effect in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you have specified (because it doesn't show all forks/merges), but it does collapse unlabeled commits to allow for a condensed viewing of the history: `gitk --all --simplify-by-decoration`